# Browsers behave differently on CSS3 transitions

Tags: css, cross-browser, transform, transition

Good morning all.

Today I'm struggling with the following code: [source on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X2eN6/4/)

What I have been trying to achieve is a seemingly simple image rollover effect where 'a mirror' of an image covers the original one using some css3 effects.

- Chrome 12 transforms the image *perfectly*
- Firefox 5 stops transformation when the image runs into mouse cursor
- IE9 - there is no transformation at all, the image is just shaking
- Opera - not checked

How do I do this cross-browser compatible?

Comment: did you try it with jquery animations ?

Comment: not yet, but I'll do unless I find my answer for CSS3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it to work in Firefox 5 the way you want. See http://jsfiddle.net/X2eN6/7/

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm. Even better after I've changed the transition method from 'ease-in-out' to 'ease-out'. Do you know any way-around for IE or a good online generator to transcode these transitions?

Comment: IE currently does not support transitions. My recommendation is to use the YUI 3 Transition module to implement a JavaScript based fallback for IE.

Comment: or jquery =) i think jquery is better than yui =)

Answer (score 1):

According to [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=transitions), IE9 doesn't support CSS3 Transitions, so I guess that's why it's not working for you in IE9.

The browsers that support the feature are Firefox (from v4), Chrome, Safari and Opera. But it's worth pointing out that transitions currently require a vendor prefix in all browsers that support them.

A vendor prefix means one of two things: either the spec is not finalised yet, so the feature is subject to possible change in syntax, or else the browser's own support for the feature is not yet considered complete.

Chrome has been supporting transitions for ages, so it's no surprise that everything works there. Firefox has only recently added it, so since they require a vendor prefix, you should take that as a warning that things may not be guaranteed to work 100%.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've used Vendor prefixes for browsers: -o -webkit -firefox

Comment: @WooDzu - it would be `-moz-` for Firefox.